# 2 unique key with one of them possible duplicate

Tags: sql, database, duplicates, unique-key

Hello I want to ask if it's possible to set 2 unique key and in some condition one of them can have duplicate but the other one is not.

The example is like this :

```
orderID          trans_date
   1          2016-02-25 01:00:00  
   1          2016-02-25 01:00:01
   2          2016-02-25 01:00:00
```

As you can see if I only make `trans_date` an unique key then it can be duplicate, it also the same as the `orderID`.
So instead of create unique id for one of them, why dont we create for both of them.
OrderID and trans_date can't be the same as the other later.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two keys to be unique as a pair, then you can create a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_example_orderid_transdate on example(orderID, trans_date);
```

Or, you can create a unique constraint which does essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to have a primary key. You can have a composite primary key on orderID and trans_date which would allow you to have more than one trans_date of same value as @Gordon has suggested.

If, for some reason, composite primary key doesn't suit your purpose you can have a trigger on the table that check all the conditions you want and allow the transaction to proceed further or not.